# <f:convert> dentro de <h:output text> no funciona

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Tengo este código, estoy jalando desde una cadena de tipo `String` y dibujando de forma dinámica, en vista quiero que se muestre con signo de dolar pero no logro que suceda.

¿Es porque estoy utilizando un `string`?

```
<h:outputText value="#{o.cadenaString}" style="color: #{o.colorCadena};">       
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="USD" currencySymbol="$" locale="en_US" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, no puede asignar el símbolo "$" (dólar) por lo mismo, para evitar generar un atributo en el bean, en los métodos de la clase crea uno que te convierta el String a double, y en el Value lo usas:

```
// En la clase...
public double getStringToDouble(){
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(this.cadenaString);  
    return amount;          
}

// En el xhtml
<h:outputText value="#{o.getStringToDouble()}" style="color: #{o.colorCadena};">
```

Espero te ayude mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: y en caso de que la cadena este sumamente laga, ¿si quisiera utilizar un BigInteger?

Comment: Veo la necesidad de usar double o float por el hecho de que lo que quieres representar es una "moneda" y como tal, necesita llevar decimales.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Comment: De nada, fue un gusto ayudarte!